# Stop rearrangement of static methods on Ctrl+Alt+L

Tags: phpstorm

I need to stop rearrangement of static methods in my classes on <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd>. Namely, all static methods are grouped at the top of a class when I apply code reformatting.

Help me to find and switch off this option from PhpStorm settings. I'm really bored with it.

These are my Arrangement tab settings:

[image]

Comment: 1) Please provide an example of what you have before and after reformat. I suggest you share the actual file content and not a screenshot (upload it somewhere and share the link). Plus, the file better have a few methods and not just 1-2. Basically, be realistic as possible (actual methods inside can have a min junk code if so desire). This is to understand what gets changed exactly and why.

Comment: 2) Have you considered disabling the code rearrange option? I personally have it turned off and re-arrange elements manually if needed. You can do that if you use `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+L` (or whatever the shortcut you may have for `Code | Reformat File...`)

Comment: 3) Now -- based on your *"all static methods are grouped at the top of a class..."* description it sounds that your static methods are somewhere below (or in the middle) and after reformat they get moved to the top. Is that correct? If so -- click on the `gear` icon (the middle right side on your screenshot) and adjust the `modifiers` entry there (or perhaps just disable the `by modifiers` option on your screenshot)

Comment: Thank you! I should guess about it by myself. I just can not imagine where this setting came from because no one among my collegues had not faced this problem.